# Form Field Submission

Tags: javascript, html, forms

I have my HTML and JS, how would I use this form in my JS so if one of the fields are not entered, the form doesnt submit and shows me my original **please enter all fields error**

Form:

```
 <form id="myForm" action="http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/~mbrown/EECS1012/testForm.php" method="get">
```

HTML:

```
    <!doctype html>
    <html lang="en">
    <head>
      <title> Forms </title>
      <style>
        span {
          padding-left: 10px;
          display: block;
          float: left;
          width: 20%;
        }
        button { margin-left: 10px; }
        body {
          width: 80%; margin: auto; font-family: sans-serif;
          border: 1px solid black;
        }
      </style>
      <meta charset="utf-8">
      <script src="prototype.js"></script>
      <script src="forms.js"></script>
    </head>
    <body>
      <h1> Keyboard  Events and Form Submit </h1>
<!-- Form -->
      <form id="myForm" action="http://www.eecs.yorku.ca/~mbrown/EECS1012/testForm.php" method="get">
      <p> <span>Name:</span> <input id="input1" value="" placeholder="Enter Name" name="Name"></p>
      <p> <span>Id:</span> <input id="input2" value=""
      placeholder="Enter ID" name="ID"></p>
      <p> <span>Email:</span> <input id="input3" value="" placeholder="Enter Email" name="Email"></p>
      <p>
      <button id="submitButton" type="button"  onclick="submit()"> Submit </button>
      <button id="resetButton" type="button"  onclick="reset()"> Reset </button>
      </p>
      <p style="color:red" id="ErrorMessage"> </p>

    </body>
    </html>
```

JS:

```
function reset(){
  document.getElementById('input1').value = "";
  document.getElementById('input2').value = "";
  document.getElementById('input3').value = "";
  document.getElementById('ErrorMessage').innerHTML = "";
}

function submit(){
  var inp1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  var inp2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  var inp3 = document.getElementById('input3').value;
  if(inp1 == "" || inp2 == "" || inp3 == "")
  {
  document.getElementById('ErrorMessage').innerHTML = "Please enter all fields";
  }
  else{
  //do your code here
  document.getElementById('ErrorMessage').innerHTML = "";
  }
}
```

Comment: Since your buttons are `type="button"` rather than `type="submit"`, they'll never submit the form. But the submit button should display the validation message that you want.

Comment: You're missing `<input type= ....` for all of input tags.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

change your function name `submit()` to another because it conflict with builtin JS function, doing `onclick="submit()"` is same with `this.form.submit()` or  `document.getElementById('myForm').submit();`

```js
function reset() {
  document.getElementById('input1').value = "";
  document.getElementById('input2').value = "";
  document.getElementById('input3').value = "";
  document.getElementById('ErrorMessage').innerHTML = "";
}

function checkSubmit() {
  var inp1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  var inp2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  var inp3 = document.getElementById('input3').value;
  if (inp1 == "" || inp2 == "" || inp3 == "") {
    document.getElementById('ErrorMessage').innerHTML = "Please enter all fields";
  } else {
    //do your code here
    document.getElementById('ErrorMessage').innerHTML = "submitting form";
    document.getElementById('myForm').submit();
  }

}
```

```css
span {
  padding-left: 10px;
  display: block;
  float: left;
  width: 20%;
}

button {
  margin-left: 10px;
}

body {
  width: 80%;
  margin: auto;
  font-family: sans-serif;
  border: 1px solid black;
}
```

```html
<h1> Keyboard Events and Form Submit </h1>
<!-- Form -->
<form id="myForm" action="https://www.eecs.yorku.ca/~mbrown/EECS1012/testForm.php" method="get">
  <p> <span>Name:</span> <input id="input1" value="" placeholder="Enter Name" name="Name"></p>
  <p> <span>Id:</span> <input id="input2" value="" placeholder="Enter ID" name="ID"></p>
  <p> <span>Email:</span> <input id="input3" value="" placeholder="Enter Email" name="Email"></p>
  <p>
    <button id="submitButton" type="button" onclick="checkSubmit()"> Submit </button>
    <button id="resetButton" type="button" onclick="reset()"> Reset </button>
  </p>
  <p style="color:red" id="ErrorMessage"> </p>
</form>
```

Answer (score 1):

Change button type to "submit" and do validation in onsubmit event handler:

```
<form onsubmit="return validateMethod()" />
```

Move all your validation logics into validateMethod, return false if the validation is failed.

Below is an example but I think you should use a jquery lib for this:

```
function validateMethod(){
  var inp1 = document.getElementById('input1').value;
  var inp2 = document.getElementById('input2').value;
  var inp3 = document.getElementById('input3').value;
  if(!inp1 || !inp2 || !inp3)
  {
     document.getElementById('ErrorMessage').innerHTML = "Please enter all fields";
     return false;
  }
  else{
      //do your code here
      document.getElementById('ErrorMessage').innerHTML = "";
      return true;
  }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

You could simply use `document.getElementById('myForm').addEventListener('submit', () => submit());`

But you need to change `<button id="submitButton" type="button"  onclick="submit()"> Submit </button>` to `<button id="submitButton" type="submit"> Submit </button>` (as Barmar said) and you also need to close your `<form>` tag.

Answer (score 1):

Upon button click of the submission button you can iterate over all the input fields, determine whether or not they have the attribute `required` and then determine whether or not their value is an empty string (`!field.value`)

We put this in a `try/catch` block so that if a field is `required` and does not have a value, we can break out of the `forEach` loop by throwing an error and displaying the message `Please Enter All Required Fields`

```js
let submit = document.querySelector("button");

submit.addEventListener("click", submitFn);

function submitFn() {
  try {
    document.querySelectorAll("form input").forEach(function(field) {
      if (field.hasAttribute("required") && !field.value) {
        throw error("not all fields filled in");
      }
    });
    alert("all required fields filled in!")
  } catch {
    alert("please enter all required fields");
  }
}
```

```html
<form>
  <label>first name </label><input required/>
  <br/>
  <label>last name</label><input required/>
  <br/>
   <label>email ( not required )</label><input />
  <hr>
  <button type="button">submit</button>
</form>
```

**Note:** It would be better code if you changed the type of the submit button to `submit` and changed the event from the above code from `click` to `submit`, but I've no idea if there was a reason for your markup or not so I leave that to your discretion.